# Delete module from database in drupal7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i install module "kvantstuio" in drupal 7, and my site crushed. i go to

> site/all/modules/kvanstudio

and delete this folder, then site work fine again. but when i click some button, i have an error

`Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Z:\home\mysite\www/sites/all/modules/kvantstudio/kvantstudio.module`

i try this open phpmyadmin, open table "block" delete all string with "kvantstudio" but the error remained. what do I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the system table, and you can delete the row with the name "kvanstudio."

In the future, if you need to manually disable a module, you can set it's status to 0 in the system table.

Comment: this error is gone but now independent modules to produce an error.. Can i delete relation in database?

Comment: Do **not** delete the system table. What is the new error you're seeing?

Comment: Warning: class_implements() [function.class-implements]: Class KvantstudioMailSystem does not exist and could not be loaded in function drupal_mail_system(). i think, that relation do not remove in database..

Comment: I think [clearing the cache](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache) should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is do a drush and then check. if that didn't work then go to your 'system' table in your phpmyadmin and see whether the module is still enabled(1) or disabled(0). you can disable module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to remove module in database :

1. `rm -rf modulePath`
2. `drush sql-query "DELETE from system where type = 'module' AND name = 'nameOfModule';"`

If it can help someone